# How do I determine and set height and scrolling position from window in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the (vertical and horizontal) scrollbar positions from a loaded html page. Then after making a backend task (e. G. deleting operation) i want to reload the page and set the old positions from scrollbar.

So how can i make this with jquery? (Getting scrollbar positions and setting it later again) I use jquery 1.8.3 at the moment. I tried some ideas, but nothing worked really.

Thanxs for your answers.

Comment: if the page is reloading then you definitely have to use use a localStorage/sessionStorage/cookie

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop()` and `$(window).scrollLeft()` will give you the scroll position. Then you'll have to do what Atif says, store the values somewhere if you intend to reload the page, and then set the position based on those values on the newly loaded page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
window.onscroll = function (oEvent) {
  // called when the window is scrolled.
}
```

and

```
// get scroll position
var x = window.scrollX,
    y = window.scrollY;
```

for get scroll position, then save x and y to cookie. After refresh read them from cookie and use code to set scroll position:

```
window.scrollTo( x, y );
```